# How to change UPS shipping method codes in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, ups

Is there a way to change default UPS shipping method codes?

For example: app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier.ups.php - 
in an array bellow if I wanted to assign 'NextDayAir' => 'Next Day Air' instead of '01' etc.
however if I change it in array its not showing up on the front page during the checkout.

'01' => 'Next Day Air',
'02' => 'Second Day Air',
'03' => 'Ground',
'07' => 'Express',
'08' => 'Expedited', 
'11' => 'Standard',